# Angular $http.get - retrieve data from url with authentication

Tags: angularjs, ajax, authentication, curl

Using Ajax in Angular I want to get some data from a URL that needs authentication. The curl command for getting this data outside of ajax is:

curl -u some_username:password 'https://website.com'

[image]

This is my function:

```
function getCurlData() {

  window.btoa("some_username:password");
  return $http.get("https://website.com").success( function(data) {
   console.log(data); 
  }).catch(function() {
     console.log("failed");      
 });
```

However I get a 403 forbidden message upon using this function. How can I retrieve the data?

Comment: Construction of the `Authorization` header is described in [Wikipedia Basic Access Authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Be aware that the server needs to set the CORS [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials).

Comment: $http({ method: 'GET', url: url, headers: { 'Authorization': "Basic "+auth64EncodedUserColonPass }}). Be aware of CORS too.

Comment: @msnfreaky I have a CORS Chrome Plugin but it still gives me an issue of access control :/